# I can't install libgfortran3 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to install libgfortran3 on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
```

But there is a error I do not understand:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-10ubuntu2) but    4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

1. Install the "best" GCC available: `sudo apt-get install gcc`.

   <= This should install "4.8.2-19ubuntu1"
2. Then install "libgfortran3" with "-force": `sudo apt-get -f install libgfortran3`.

   <= libfortran is apparantly "expecting" gcc 4.8.2-10.  This shouldn't be a problem...
3. Make sure everything works.

Please post back if you have any problems or questions.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will not work if there is already a newer version of gcc installed. You still can install the lib by downloading and installing it manually:

```
apt download libgfortran3
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends libgfortran [your version] .deb
```

But this will make apt complain about unmatched dependencies from now on. This can be temporarily fixed by manually altering the dependency for libgfortran in

```
/var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I found this solution when I tried to install r-base on a ubuntu xenial system with gcc-5.4.0 already present while libgfortran3 asked for precisely 5.3.1-14ubuntu2. Credits for this solution go [here](https://superuser.com/questions/739274/ignore-all-dependencies-for-a-specific-package-with-apt-get)